# How to access Java Spark Broadcast variable?

Tags: java, apache-spark

i am trying to broadcast a `Dataset` in spark in order to access it from within a `map` function. The first print statement returns the first line of the broadcasted dataset as expected. Unfortunately, the second print statement does not return a result. The execution simply hangs at this point. 
Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
    Broadcast<JavaRDD<Row>> broadcastedTrainingData = this.javaSparkContext.broadcast(trainingData.toJavaRDD());

    System.out.println("Data:" + broadcastedTrainingData.value().first());
    JavaRDD<Row> rowRDD = this.javaSparkContext.parallelize(stringAsList).map((Integer row) -> {
        System.out.println("Data (map):" + broadcastedTrainingData.value().first());
        return RowFactory.create(row);
    });
```

The following **pseudocode** hightlights what i want to achieve. My main goal is to broadcast the training dataset, so i can use it from within a map function.

```
    public Dataset<Row> getWSSE(Dataset<Row> trainingData, int clusterRange) {
        StructType structType = new StructType();
        structType = structType.add("ClusterAm", DataTypes.IntegerType, false);
        structType = structType.add("Cost", DataTypes.DoubleType, false);

        List<Integer> stringAsList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int clusterAm = 2; clusterAm < clusterRange + 2; clusterAm++) {
            stringAsList.add(clusterAm);
        }

        Broadcast<Dataset> broadcastedTrainingData = this.javaSparkContext.broadcast(trainingData);

        System.out.println("Data:" + broadcastedTrainingData.value().first());
        JavaRDD<Row> rowRDD = this.javaSparkContext.parallelize(stringAsList).map((Integer row) -> RowFactory.create(row));

        StructType schema = DataTypes.createStructType(new StructField[]{DataTypes.createStructField("ClusterAm", DataTypes.IntegerType, false)});

        Dataset wsse = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rowRDD, schema).toDF();
        wsse.show();

        ExpressionEncoder<Row> encoder = RowEncoder.apply(structType);

        Dataset result = wsse.map(
                (MapFunction<Row, Row>) row -> RowFactory.create(row.getAs("ClusterAm"), new KMeans().setK(row.getAs("ClusterAm")).setSeed(1L).fit(broadcastedTrainingData.value()).computeCost(broadcastedTrainingData.value())),
                encoder);

        result.show();
        broadcastedTrainingData.destroy();
        return wsse;
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean "does not return a result"? A print should be printed in your standard output on the executor side. Did you check that? Also, do you have an action? All I see is a map operation, which is a transformation (will not be executed until an action is invoked). Can you create a [mcve]? Also, don't broadcast RDDs. The executors are not supposed to know anything about them.

Comment: The program does not proceed the execution, it simply seems to hang (hence, no further output to stdout). I extended the problem description with a pseudocode example. Why shouldn't i broadcast RDDs?

Comment: Because RDD operations are not available in the executors, only in the driver, which has a SparkContext - which the executors do not have. If you want to combine Rdds you should look at join operations.

Comment: I see the issue now. Is there a best practice to access an external dataset from within a map function? (seems like a common situation)

Comment: Not really, because datasets are not available within a map function. It requires re-thinking your algorithm. Executors can only access partitions of datasets, not whole datasets. They can access shared files or small broadcast objects if needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
        DataSet<Row> trainingData = ...<Your dataset>;
                            
       //Creating the broadcast variable. No need to write classTag code by hand 
       // use akka.japi.Util which is available
                        
        Broadcast<Dataset<Row>> broadcastedTrainingData = spark.sparkContext()
              .broadcast(trainingData, akka.japi.Util.classTag(DataSet.class));
                            
        //Here is the catch.When you are iterating over a Dataset, 
        //Spark will actally run it in distributed mode. So if you try to accees
        //Your object directly (e.g. trainingData) it would be null . 
        //Cause you didn't ask spark to explicitly send tha outside variable to
        //each machine where you are running this for each parallelly.
        //So you need to use Broadcast variable.(Most common use of Broadcast)  
        
        someSparkDataSet.foreach((row) -> {
         DataSet<Row>  recieveBrdcast = broadcastedTrainingData.value();
         ...
         ...
        })
```